# passing pointer to function binded by std::bind to another class produces access violation

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, stdbind

I have the following two methods in my class ObstaclesDetector and I'm trying to pass a callback using std::bind to the constructor of another class called ASLnetDecompressor, but once I call the Start() method which probably invokes the callback, the program crashes with an Access violation.

If I pass the reference to the static function (radarCallback) directly, it works.

It seems to me that the pointer does not address a globally accessible memory but I don't know how to fix it. Do you have any ideas?

The code:

```
include "obstacles_detector.h"
using namespace std::placeholders;
...
void ObstaclesDetector::detectObstacles(float range, ObstaclesDescriptor *desc) {
    auto callback = std::bind(ObstaclesDetector::radarCallback, _1, _2, _3); // just to test it, does not make sense, of course
    ASLnetDecompressor net((ASLnetDecoderCallback*) &callback, desc, 4096, 4378);

    net.Start(); // Access violation executing location {address of callback}
}
...
void ObstaclesDetector::radarCallback(void *arg,const ReturnHeader *h, unsigned char *data) { // a static function (defined in header file)
    printf("AAA\n");
}
```

Comment: Is `radarCallback` a static or non-static member function? What is `ASLnetDecompressor`? What is `ASLnetDecompressor ::Start` and what does it do? Can you please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: radarCallback is static.

Comment: Also, the type returned by [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) can't be converted to any other type. It's an implementation-specific type and the problem is probably with you trying to use it as a totally different type. Not to mention that you pass a pointer to a local variable which goes out of scope and is destructed once the `detectObstacles` function ends.

Comment: "If I pass the reference to the static function (radarCallback) directly, it works" - yes, because that's a function with the correct type. You're casting a pointer to an object to a function pointer. Useful rule of thumb: when you cast anything to a function pointer type, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: thanks, you were right, the std::bind does not return a function pointer. So finally, I gave up this approach and used the second parameter of the ASLnetDecompressor (an external class) constructor to pass the needed parameters and it seems to work. @molbdnillo - yes it was a smelly (and ultimately not working) approach, I admit